# How to echo only one post from a jsonfile

Tags: php, json, echo, instagram

I have made a Module which displays the latest images from a instagram profile, and it works perfectly in Joomla 3.4.8 with a small popup gallery
I would like to add the profile image - profile_picture, but of course it should only appear once.
I have tried various php echo - but no luck

Can anyone help?

The PHP

```
<?php
    // Supply a user id and an access token
    $userid = $params->get('klintweb_insta_id');
    $accessToken = $params->get('klintweb_insta_access_token');
    $count = $params->get('klintweb_insta_count');

    // Gets post and image
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }

    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?count={$count}&access_token={$accessToken}");
    $result = json_decode($result);


?>
```

The foreach

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    {emailcloak=off}
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
    <span class="KlintWebInstaSpan">
        <a data-mediabox-group="insta" type="image/jpeg" class="jcepopup noicon" data-mediabox-caption="<?= rtrim(strip_tags(substr ($post->caption->text,0,140))).'...'; ?>" data-mediabox-title="rasmusjorgensen128" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>">
            <img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>" alt="Billede fra instagram" />
            <span class="overlay"></span>
        </a>
    </span>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The jsonfile

```
{
"data": [{
    "comments": {
        "count": 0
    },
    "caption": {
        "created_time": "1296710352",
        "text": "Inside le truc #foodtruck",
        "from": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
            "type": "user",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "id": "26621408"
    },
    "likes": {
        "count": 15
    },
    "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BWrVZ/",
    "user": {
        "username": "kevin",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "created_time": "1296710327",
    "images": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_6.jpg",
            "width": 306,
            "height": 306
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_5.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_7.jpg",
            "width": 612,
            "height": 612
        }
    },
    "type": "image",
    "users_in_photo": [],
    "filter": "Earlybird",
    "tags": ["foodtruck"],
    "id": "22721881",
    "location": {
        "latitude": 37.778720183610183,
        "longitude": -122.3962783813477,
        "id": "520640",
        "street_address": "",
        "name": "Le Truc"
    }
},
{
    "videos": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 480
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
        },
    "comments": {
        "count": 2
    },
    "caption": null,
    "likes": {
        "count": 1
    },
    "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
    "created_time": "1279340983",
    "images": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_6.jpg",
            "width": 306,
            "height": 306
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_5.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_7.jpg",
            "width": 612,
            "height": 612
        }
    },
    "type": "video",
    "users_in_photo": null,
    "filter": "Vesper",
    "tags": [],
    "id": "363839373298",
    "user": {
        "username": "kevin",
        "full_name": "Kevin S",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "location": null
},
```

]
}

**Thanks to Adam Taylor**
You pointed how simple it can be done

Also thanks to Danoweb for helping

Comment: As You can see there is a "count" in the url. If eg the count is 4, the gallery displays the thumbnails from the latest 4 posts
I want to display the "profile_picture" once above the 4 thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in understanding you're looping through a list of photos and you want to also access the profile picture and print it once?

Do you need to loop through all the photos? If not, you could add a `break` after you've printed the photo, to exit the loop.

If you need to loop through the photos as well, why not access the first element in the JSON, take the profile picture from there, and then loop through the rest of the photos?

Edit:
In regards to your solution, it might be easier to just access the first photo directly, print the associated user thumbnail, and then continue with your loop and printing of all the photos. Something like:

```
<div class="user">
  <?php $post = $result->data[0]; ?>
    <img src="<?= $post->user->profile_picture ?>" alt="<?= $post->user->username ?>" />
    <span class="username"><?= $post->user->username ?></span>
</div>

<!-- do the rest of your looping/displaying photos -->
```

In your solution you are slicing the array to one element and then looping over the array when all you really want to do is access the first element.

Comment: As you can see there is a "count" in the url. If I eg set the to 4, the gallery will display the thumbs from the four latest posts on his instagram site in a divider. I want to display the profile picture once above the gallery. Your suggestion sounds right - but how do I do it?

Comment: I've added an example and commented on your solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it looks like the profile picture is provided twice within the JSON response.  What I would use is a variable to track whether or not I have already shown the profile picture, and if so, don't show the second one.  For Example:

```
<?php
$shown_profile = false;
foreach ($result->data as $post)
{
    //WE HAVE NOT SHOWN PROFILE PIC, SHOW IT AND SET FLAG.
    if($shown_profile == false and (image is profile pic) )
    {
        $shown_profile = true;
    }

    //WE HAVE ALREADY SHOWN PROFILE PIC AND THIS IMAGE IS A DUPLICATE
    if($shown_profile == true and (image is profile pic) )
    {
        //JUMP TO THE NEXT LOOP INTERATION
        continue;
    }
    //[THE REST OF YOUR FOREACH CODE]
}

?>
```

You can find more info about the "continue" statement here:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand what you mean, and it looks quite correctly. 
But unfortunately I can not figure out the values - eg where is profile_picture?  

Would you be so kind to write it a little more detail

Comment: OH!  I see now, so what you can do is take in that JSON data (file read or however you are getting it) and then pass it to:  `json_decode(data);`  This will give you a PHP Array.  You can then `print_r(array);` and see the output of the json (and it various dimensions!).  So if you made `$json_data_array = json_decode(data);`, I would guess you could use:  `$json_data_array['data']['user']['profile_picture']` to get the URL in the JSON  (Depending on how you are accessing the JSON, you may not need the initial ['data'] dimension.  Hope this helps!